# how to mask a video in createjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I was looking at doing something along the lines of what is done here:

http://viget.com/extend/masking-video-tags-using-html5-canvas

Where the globalCompositeOperation is used to set the masked area.

```
function drawMaskedVideo() {
    ctx.save();

    // Draw the video feed
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    // Set the composite operation, which is responsible for masking
    // see https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';

    // Apply the mask
    ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);

    ctx.restore();
}

requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop.bind(this));
    drawMaskedVideo();
});
```

However I'm not sure how well this will integrate with createjs, has anyone seen it done in createjs, I haven't found any examples, although I did notice that a bitmap source can be a video. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Video as a source for a Bitmap. You can then mask the Bitmap. The Bitmap just does a drawImage() with the source whenever the stage is updated. Note that the mask will orient itself with the Bitmap, so you don't need to manually move the mask, unless you want to change it relative to the video.

```
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(videoHTMLTag);
bmp.mask = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#000").drawRect(0,0,100,100));
```

Make sure to update the stage constantly, or the video will not change from the first time it gets rendered.

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

Comment: So the bitmap will update automatically on stage.update()? I assumed I would need to do that manually, I had got it working creating a new bitmap each tick

Comment: When the stage updates, the Bitmap redraws the source to the canvas. If the source changes, then it will show on the canvas. Note that if you cache it, then it would not update. You do not have to create a new Bitmap each time.

Answer (score 0):

> You can move the container to whatever the position you want to and
>   offfset the image contained to the position you want.The can be done
>   by adding the image that you want to mask to the container.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843493/easeljs-using-updatecache-with-alphamaskfilter-when-dragging-mask) one for more info.I think this is what you wanted

Comment: That example doesn't use a video as the source though? I am trying something along those lines, creating a new Bitmap every frame, adding to the stage, masking and removing the old. Not sure what the overhead will be though